# In orientDB , im unable to go to localhost:2480 after starting server

Tags: orientdb

First i unzip binary distribution and start the server and then go to the localhost:2480. the result is web pag not available. I turned off firewall as well

Comment: which distribution have you downloaded?

Comment: could you please copy/paste the server console logs? You should see port numbers